# Apache FOP | Multi page table row height issue

Tags: row, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am generating PDF using Apache FOP XSL file format.

**My requirements are**

- Tabular data in PDF
- Table size is large so the Same table extended to multiple pages (width-wise, few columns in first page others are on the next page)
- Page 1 has 3 columns (C1, C2, C3)
- Page 2 has 5 columns (C4, C5, C6, C7, C8)
- Few cells may have multiline data

**Problem description:**

- When Page-2 has multiline data for Row 4, Column 4, so its row height increased as per content
  [image]
- But in Page-1 row 4 has row height as a single line.

[image]

**I want to have the same row height across all pages of the same table when any cell data is multiline of any page.**

Here is XSL file if needed:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    version="1.0">

  <!-few params declaration->

    <xsl:template match="/rs">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="data-template-1" page-height="11.0in" page-width="17.0in"
                                       margin-top="0.5in" margin-bottom="1.0in" margin-left="0.5in"
                                       margin-right="0.5in">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="0.8in"/>
                    <fo:region-before extent="0.7in"/>
                    <fo:region-after/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="data-template-2" page-height="11.0in" page-width="17.0in"
                                       margin-top="0.5in" margin-bottom="1.0in" margin-left="0.5in"
                                       margin-right="0.5in">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="0.8in"/>
                    <fo:region-before extent="0.7in"/>
                    <fo:region-after/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>

            <xsl:for-each select="rb">
                <xsl:variable name="current-initial-page-number" select="$param.initialPageNumber + (position() * $pagesPerTable)" />
                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="data-template-1" initial-page-number="{$current-initial-page-number}"
                                  font-size="{$cdrFontSize}" font-family="{$cdrFontFamily}" line-height="10.2pt">
                    
                    
                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" space-after.optimum="{$cdrInfoTableSpaceAfter}" border-width="0.4mm" border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-column column-width="23.1mm"/>
                            <fo:table-column column-width="23.1mm"/>
                            <fo:table-column column-width="18.9mm"/>
                            
                            <fo:table-header text-align="center" display-align="center">
                                <fo:table-row font-weight="bold" background-color="rgb(230,230,230)">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="cdr_table_cell">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="cellValue" select="'C1'"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                    <xsl:call-template name="cdr_table_cell">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="cellValue" select="'C2'"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                    <xsl:call-template name="cdr_table_cell">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="cellValue" select="'C3"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                    
                                </fo:table-row>
                            </fo:table-header>

                            <fo:table-body>
                                <xsl:for-each select="r">
                                    <fo:table-row text-align="left" display-align="before">
                                        <xsl:call-template name="cdr_table_cell">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="cellValue" select="c[@n='C1']"/>
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                        <xsl:call-template name="cdr_table_cell">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="cellValue" select="c[@n='C12']"/>
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                        <xsl:call-template name="cdr_table_cell">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="cellValue" select="c[@n='C3']"/>
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                        
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:flow>
                </fo:page-sequence>
                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="data-template-2"
                                  font-size="{$cdrFontSize}" font-family="{$cdrFontFamily}" line-height="10.2pt">
                    
                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" space-after.optimum="{$cdrInfoTableSpaceAfter}" border-width="0.4mm" border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-column column-width="88.2mm"/>
                            <fo:table-column column-width="88.2mm"/>
                            <fo:table-column column-width="48.3mm"/>
                            <fo:table-column column-width="23.1mm"/>
                            <fo:table-column column-width="54.6mm"/>
                            <fo:table-header text-align="center" display-align="center">
                                <fo:table-row font-weight="bold" background-color="rgb(230,230,230)">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="cdr_table_cell">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="cellValue" select="'C4'"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                    <xsl:call-template name="cdr_table_cell">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="cellValue" select="'C5'"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                    <xsl:call-template name="cdr_table_cell">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="cellValue" select="'C6'"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                    <xsl:call-template name="cdr_table_cell">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="cellValue" select="'C7'"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                    <xsl:call-template name="cdr_table_cell">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="cellValue" select="'C8'"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                </fo:table-row>R
                            </fo:table-header>

                            <fo:table-body>
                                <xsl:for-each select="r">
                                    <fo:table-row text-align="left" display-align="before">
                                        <xsl:call-template name="cdr_table_cell">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="cellValue" select="c[@n='C4']"/>
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                        <xsl:call-template name="cdr_table_cell">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="cellValue" select="c[@n='C5']"/>
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                        <xsl:call-template name="cdr_table_cell">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="cellValue" select="c[@n='C6']"/>
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                        <xsl:call-template name="cdr_table_cell">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="cellValue" select="c[@n='C7']"/>
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                        <xsl:call-template name="cdr_table_cell">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="cellValue" select="c[@n='C8']"/>
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:flow>
                </fo:page-sequence>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="cdr_table_cell">
        <xsl:param name="cellValue"/>
        <fo:table-cell border-width="0.4mm" border-style="solid">
            <fo:block-container overflow="hidden">
                <fo:block margin-left="0.5mm" margin-top="0.3mm">
                    <xsl:call-template name="zero_width_space_1">
                        <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$cellValue"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- The following templates are used to add empty space character to data, so that FOP can break (wrap) the word -->
    <xsl:template name="zero_width_space_1">
        <xsl:param name="data"/>
        <xsl:param name="counter" select="0"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$counter &lt;= string-length($data)">
                <xsl:value-of select='concat(substring($data,$counter,1),"&#8203;")'/>
                <xsl:call-template name="zero_width_space_2">
                    <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$data"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="$counter+1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="'&#160;'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="zero_width_space_2">
        <xsl:param name="data"/>
        <xsl:param name="counter"/>
        <xsl:value-of select='concat(substring($data,$counter,1),"&#8203;")'/>
        <xsl:call-template name="zero_width_space_1">
            <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$data"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="$counter+1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**What I don't want**

- Fixed row height as it wastes page space even if all data is accumulated in a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format the full table twice: once for each page.

For the first copy of the table, make everything after column 3 be white or transparent.

For the second copy of the table, make everything in columns 1 to 3 be white or transparent and also add a negative margin on the table (and set it back to 0 in the table cells) so that columns 1 to 3 are off the left side of the page.

Note that if you were using AH Formatter, you could use the Spread Page Master extension (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/v70e/ahf-spread.html) and make a region that spans both pages.

Comment: I didn't get how this solve my row height problem? You explained about generating 2 pages only that I already happening.

Comment: You currently generate two pages by generating half of the table on each page. The problem is that the left-hand doesn't know what the right-hand is doing. You can work around it by formatting the full table on each page but make the parts that belong on the other page invisible on the current page.  For the right-hand page, you also need to shift the table to the left so that it looks like the table starts with the first visible column.